# Find the longest subsequence of two strings

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, dynamic-programming, subsequences

I want to know which is the best way to find the longest common subsequence of two strings

Comment: What method did you try to use, and why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I used dynamic programming to find a string that is not a subsequence of A and another string that is not a subsequence of B and try to get something out of it. But my approach is wrong

Comment: Just a clarification, do you want a subsequence, or substring?

Comment: Wait! Your last edit totally changed the problem/question you are asking about.  Don't do that.

Comment: This link might help you.. http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html

Answer (score 1):

You know the recipe for dynamic programming: define some subproblems, then show how to use solutions to smaller subproblems to help you solve larger subproblems.  So, what you have tried as candidate subproblems?

Hint: When you have a dynamic programming problem that takes a string as input, what are some candidate ways to define subproblems?  (Prefixes, suffices, substrings...)  Now, how might you apply that general advice here?

I'm not going to spell out the full answer, as this sounds like homework, and to learn from homework, you need to struggle with it yourself.

Comment: Here OP talks about subsequences not substring, and seems he knows basics of DP.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I tried to remove longest common subsequence in both and try out with the rest. But it was not the right approach

Comment: @D.W. I know what dynamic programming is but I am not able think of the subproblem that is right for me

Comment: @user8105 Don't expect us to solve the assignment for you. Continue thinking, and eventually you'll find the solution.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have solved the problem